# Why does removeChild() not work in select option

Tags: javascript, arrays, drop-down-menu

```
var arr = {'ukraine' : ['Киев', 'Одесса', 'Харьков'], 'russia' : ['Петербург', "Москва", "Архангельск"], 'belarus' : ['Минск', 'Витебск', 'Гомель']};
var countries = document.getElementById('country');
var cities = document.getElementById('cities');
cities.style.visibility = 'hidden';
countries.addEventListener('change', func);
function func(){
    var temp = countries.value;
    var city = arr[temp];
    if(cities.options != undefined){
        for(var i = 0; i < cities.options.length; i++){
            alert(i);
            cities.removeChild(cities.options[i]);
        }
}
    for(var i = 0; i < city.length; i++){
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.innerHTML = city[i];
        cities.appendChild(option);
    }
    cities.style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

These russian words mean cities. What I'm trying to do is to display second select depending on the option I choose in the first one. But when I'm trying to delete all old options of cities select, it just deletes the first option, even though I put it in the loop? Why does removeChild only work for the first child?

Comment: Can you share your html?

Comment: It's not that `removeChild` wouldn't work. It's the live collection `options` returns causing your issue. When you're iterating through a live collection and remove elements from the collection, the iteration skips some elements, as the indexing of the collection changes. Instead of `options` collection, use `cities.querySelectorAll('option')` which returns a static NodeList, or create an array of the `options` collection and use that when removing children.